# ¿Como Crear APIRest Con Go y Framework ECHO?

Tags: javascript, go

Estoy intentando hacer un `APIRest` con el `framework` `ECHO` para el lenguaje `GO`, pero me encuentro con la siguiente dificultad, yo lo que deseo es hacer una petición `fetch` con `javascript`, en donde envio en encabezado de una factura y su respectivo detalle, el problema es que no se como recorrer los datos, mi código es el siguiente:

**HTML:**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="msj"></div>
<script>
    var detalles = [];
    var detalle = {
        Codigo      : '123',
        Descripcion : 'Azucar',
        Cantidad    : '1',
        Valor       : '5'
    };
    detalles.push(detalle);
    var detalle = {
        Codigo      : '321',
        Descripcion : 'Arroz',
        Cantidad    : '2',
        Valor       : '1'
    };
    detalles.push(detalle);

    var datos ={ 
        "Cliente"       :'Andres', 
        "Direccion"     :'Calle Falsa 123', 
        "Email"         :'a@a.com', 
        "Detalles"      : detalles,
    }

    var url1 = "http://localhost:1323/"
    fetch(url1,
    {
        headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(datos)
    })
    .then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
    .then(function(data){ document.getElementById("msj").innerHTML = JSON.stringify( data );  })
    .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Hubo un problema con la petición Fetch:' + error);
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**CÓDIGO GO:**

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/labstack/echo"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/middleware"
)

type Detalle struct {
    Codigo      string `json:"codigo" form:"codigo" query:"codigo"`
    Descripcion string `json:"descripcion" form:"descripcion" query:"descripcion"`
    Cantidad    string `json:"cantidad" form:"cantidad" query:"cantidad"`
    Valor       string `json:"valor" form:"valor" query:"valor"`
}
type Factura struct {
    Cliente   string `json:"cliente" form:"cliente" query:"cliente"`
    Direccion string `json:"direccion" form:"direccion" query:"direccion"`
    Email     string `json:"email" form:"email" query:"email"`
    Detalles  []Detalle
}

func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    e.Use(middleware.CORSWithConfig(middleware.CORSConfig{
        AllowOrigins: []string{"*"},
        AllowMethods: []string{echo.GET, echo.PUT, echo.POST, echo.DELETE},
    }))
    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.String(http.StatusOK, "Hello, World!")
    })
    e.POST("/", save)
    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
}

func save(c echo.Context) (err error) {
    u := new(Factura)

    if err = c.Bind(u); err != nil {
        return c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Error")
    }
    return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, u)
}
```

Estoy tratando de guiarme de la [documentación](https://echo.labstack.com/guide/request) pero aun no consigo lograrlo, la idea es recorrer el detalle para hacer la inserción en la BD.

Comment: no entendi con lo de recorrer el detalle, te refieres a recorrer el struct Factura y recorrer los detalles ??

Comment: @kiramishima recorrer el detalle, pero ya lo solucione haciendo un for range al detalle, de igual forma, gracias :)