# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el listado tablas Mysql con Go?

Tags: mysql, go, show

Quiero obtener el listado de tablas de una base de datos con Go, pero no encuentro la forma de ejecutar correctamente ("SHOW TABLES"). No me funciona, no encuentro información.

El driver que uso es `"github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"`

¿Alguna idea?

```
// Connect to source database
db, err := sql.Open("mysql", config.DB_SOURCE_USER+":"+config.DB_SOURCE_PASS+"@"+config.DB_SOURCE_HOST+"/"+config.DB_SOURCE_NAME+"?charset=utf8")
checkErr(err)

register, err := db.Exec("SHOW TABLES")
checkErr(err)

fmt.Println(register)

db.Close()
```

Gracias

Comment: ¿Imprime algo? ¿Seguro que estás conectado correctamente a la BD? ¿Tienes privilegios sobre las tablas que quieres mostrar? [Mira esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43884296/5587982) del sitio en inglés.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa el código de la pregunta: [problema al crear web service con go](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167884/problema-al-crear-webservice-en-golang).
Básicamente es algo así:

```
*SELECT*/
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT su.coduser AS id , TRIM(su.nomuser) AS user, s.fchven AS fch_ven, s.fecreg AS fch_registro FROM suser su JOIN sinfo s ON s.coduser = su.coduser WHERE su.nomuser=? AND su.pass=?",user_login,pass_login)
    cols, _ := rows.Columns()

    for rows.Next() {
        // Create a slice of interface{}'s to represent each column,
        // and a second slice to contain pointers to each item in the columns slice.
        columns := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
        columnPointers := make([]interface{}, len(cols))
        for i, _ := range columns {
            columnPointers[i] = &columns[i]
        }

        // Scan the result into the column pointers...
        if err := rows.Scan(columnPointers...); err != nil {
            //return err
        }

        // Create our map, and retrieve the value for each column from the pointers slice,
        // storing it in the map with the name of the column as the key.
        m := make(map[string]interface{})
        for i, colName := range cols {
            val := columnPointers[i].(*interface{})
            m[colName] = *val
        }

        // Outputs: map[columnName:value columnName2:value2 columnName3:value3 ...]
        fmt.Print(m)
    }
```